# Writing Processing mini-library, need to make variable name from string?

Tags: java, processing

I'm making a sprite based library for [Processing](https://processing.org/), in which I have a system for adding images to the program. I have a method inside a Sprite class that asks for a `PImage` as a parameter.

```
ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<String> i = images.iterator();

void addImage(String img) {
  images.add(img);
}

void loadImages() {
  while(i.hasNext()) {
    String img = i.next();
    PImage ??? = loadImage(img);
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to name the `PImage` variable the name of the file, which I have saved as "img". I want to make this library as accessible as possible for people to experiment with sprites, similar to the MIT's [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/) program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't create variables like that. But you can use a **`HashMap`** to accomplish your goal.

Basically, a `HashMap` allows you to map keys to values. You could use `String` keys that map to `PImage` values, something like this:

```
HashMap<String, PImage> imageMap = new HashMap<String, PImage>();
imageMap.put("imageOne", loadImage("giraffe.jpg"));
imageMap.put("imageTwo", loadImage("elephant.jpg"));

image(imageMap.get("imageOne"), 0, 0);
```

If you wanted to create a library that tracks image files, you could have the user specify the key value along with the `PImage` instance. Something like this:

```
HashMap<String, PImage> imageMap = new HashMap<String, PImage>();

void addImage(String key, String imageLocation) {
  imageMap.put(key, loadImage(imageLocation));
}

PImage getImage(String key){
   return imageMap.get(key);
}
```

Or you could just use the `imageLocation` as the key.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java is not quite so dynamic as to create actual Java variables on the fly, and your user would have to know the names in advance to use them.

A HashMap would provide the functionality. Using Apache's FilenameUtils (or your code), you extract the name of the image from its filename/URL/etc, and store the loaded image in a HashMap using that basename as the key. This example uses the basename, but you can create whatever key you like from the input name.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

HashMap<String, PImage> images = new HashMap<String, PImage>();

public String addImageURI(String imageURI) {
    String basename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(imageURI);
    images.put(basename, loadImage(imageURI);
}

public PImage getImage(String imageKey) {
    return images.get(imageKey);
}
```